# How to pass in a method name of a particular class as a parameter of another method

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I'm trying to write a C# method that generates threads by passing in an object and running one of its methods.

Here is an oversimplified example:

```
class ThreadData {
    private JObject jsonObj;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    public ThreadData(JObject jsonObj, int start, int end) {
        this.jsonObj= jsonObj;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    public void Calculate() {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    public void Produce() {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        JObject jsonObj= SomeRestAPICall();
        RunInThreads(5, jsonObj, Calculate);
        RunInThreads(5, jsonObj, Produce);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The json object has n number of items. The RunInThreads method's goal is to generate X number of threads, divide up the jsonObj into equal X chunks, and have each thread run on each chunk. I pass into the method the number of threads, the json object as well as a method to run ThreadData class.

```
private static void RunInThreads(int numOfThreads, JObject object, type functionToRun) {
    int chunks = object.Count() / numOfThreads;
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfThreads; i++) {
        int start = (i - 1) * chunks;
        int end = i == numOfThreads? object.Count() : start + chunks;

        ThreadData threadData = new ThreadData(object, start, end);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadData.<FUNCTION>));
        thread.Start();
        threads.Add(thread);
    }
    foreach (Thread t in threads) { t.Join(); }
}
```

I can't quite figure out how to pass in the function name as a parameter. Would I use a delegate? If I was using two separate methods I would put in the custom method name in each one. For instance, for the Calculate() method it would be as such:

```
private static void CalculateInThreads(int numOfThreads, JObject object) {
    int chunks = object.Count() / numOfThreads;
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfThreads; i++) {
        int start = (i - 1) * chunks;
        int end = i == numOfThreads? object.Count() : start + chunks;

        ThreadData threadData = new ThreadData(object);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadData.functionToRun));
        thread.Start();
        threads.Add(thread);
    }
    foreach (Thread t in threads) { t.Join(); }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe something like this would work:

```
private static void RunInThreads(int numOfThreads, JObject object, 
                                 Action<ThreadData> functionToRun) {
    int chunks = object.Count() / numOfThreads;
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfThreads; i++) {
        int start = (i - 1) * chunks;
        int end = i == numOfThreads? object.Count() : start + chunks;

        ThreadData threadData = new ThreadData(object, start, end);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => functionToRun(threadData));
        thread.Start();
        threads.Add(thread);
    }
    foreach (Thread t in threads) { t.Join(); }
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
RunInThreads(5, jsonObj, t=>t.Calculate());
```

To explain the syntax:

`Action<ThreadData>` is an [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) - a predefined delegate that takes one input parameter and returns void.

The `t => t.Calculate()` syntax is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb397687.aspx) that represents an instance of the delegate - it's basically a short way to define an inline function which takes a single parameter `t`. The type of `t` is inferred to be `ThreadData` because the compiler knows the delegate is an `Action<ThreadData>`.

You could write the same thing with more keypresses like this:

```
void DoCalculate(ThreadData data)
{
    data.Calculate();
}
...
RunInThread(5, jsonObj, new Action<ThreadData>(DoCalculate));
```

Comment: Awesome--thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain the "t=>t.Calculate()" syntax? What does "t" mean here and how does it know Calculate() is a valid method in this context?

Comment: No problem! Edited!

Comment: Thanks, that explained it.